# Checking the DB_LINK Connection

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I just created a DB link using the following query in oracle:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK LINK_NAME
CONNECT TO DB_USERNAME
IDENTIFIED BY DB_USERNAME'S_PASSWORD
USING 'SERVICE_NAME';
```

and i'm able to see few more infos like owner,db_link,username,host,created details when viewed from sql developer.

How to use `SELECT` query in order to check the link connectivity to that `DB_USERNAME` or kindly suggest me a way to check the same ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
select * from dual@LINK_NAME
```

Comment: @MikeGauty - it means no connect.

Comment: What i found is, provided the `service name` wrongly, i hope.. would you please share the format to enter the `service name` while creating db link where my requirement is to connect to a DB running on another machine

Comment: Bullet-proof solution is to use full connection string `create database link LINK_NAME connect to scott identified by tiger using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.1.1.1)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=your_service_name)))';`